# How To Stop Cmd Window From Scrolling Down Automatically

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, batch, cmd.exe

I'm making a batch file that runs some ffmpeg commands. When ffmpeg is encoding, it shows you the progress of the encode, updating it every second or so.

The problem is that sometimes I want to scroll up in the command window. But when I try to do this, the command window snaps back to the bottom to show me the progress bar of the ffmpeg encode.

How can I get command to stop automatically scrolling me to the bottom every time the progress bar updates?

I've tried the Scroll Lock key, it didn't work.
I would like it if there was a command I could use.

Comment: Im not sure why people are voting to close this. The question is both well written and clear.

Comment: See if anything here helps: https://superuser.com/questions/1145483/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-pause-the-output-of-a-cmd-window-while-its-runn

Comment: do you need to see the progress? you may just be able to turn the progress off or send it to nul.

Answer (score 0):

I know 2 methods:

1. Use "pause" key or its analog https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Break_key#Modern_keyboards, click "enter" to continue
2. Use mouse-click on console - it will start text selecting mode and pause scrolling in the same time for this, to cancel selecting mode click "esc" or "enter" to copy the selection - scrolling will continue after this