# Is there an shortcut to just pause without suspend in terminal?

Tags: terminal, putty, windows-11

In putty, the program running inside in screen is paused (Not just output when Ctrl+S is pressed but the whole program) (don't know how but some output is selected; somehow SIGSTOP is sent) and after pressing Enter resumes like [the behavior in windows cmd](https://superuser.com/a/1520256/687987). Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Terminal, (and also Command Prompt), you can press the Pause/Break key on your keyboard to freeze the screen and pauses the execution of the current command. Press any key to continue. (useful to just look at the screen)

If you disable quick edit mode, left click and drag will start a selection which both pauses the screen and pauses the execution of the current command until enter is pressed. (useful to interact with the output)

Comment: In Putty Terminal?